# PHP Prevent SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I'm trying to prevent SQL Injection using PHP with PDO. I've used this as a reference. http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers . My code doesn't give me any error but the values that are getting in are all null.

The vlaues I'm trying to insert are **not** null. I know this because I've echo'ed them out: 
`echo "\nDate: ".$date." Name: ".$name." mail: ".$mail."Comment: ".$comment." website: ".$website;`

```
$sql = "INSERT post SET timeDate = :timeDate and name = :name and mail = :mail and comment = :comment and website = :website";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":timeDate", $date);
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $name);
$stmt->bindParam(":mail", $mail);
$stmt->bindParam(":comment", $comment);
$stmt->bindParam(":website", $website);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: On a side note, you don't actually need such a long and winding code, two lines are actually enough: [PDO Examples: UPDATE query using PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/update)

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT post SET name=?, mail=?";`
`$db->prepare($sql)->execute([$name, $mail]);` But Is this Injection safe?

Comment: yes but you need to add other fields as well

Comment: Other fields as in?

Comment: as in your query

Comment: @YourCommonSense, MySQL supports a nonstandard syntax for a single-row `INSERT...SET` that is similar to `UPDATE` syntax. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: @bill his problem is different one

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `AND` in between your assignments—use commas.

```
$sql = "INSERT post
        SET timeDate = :timeDate,
            name = :name,
            mail = :mail,
            comment = :comment,
            website = :website";
```

Your statement using `AND` between the terms is no error, because the statement is actually valid. It just doesn't do what you thought it would.

It's as if you did this:

```
SET timeDate = (:timeDate and name = :name and mail = :mail and comment = :comment and website = :website")
```

This sets only timeDate to the result of one long boolean expression.

The other columns are not getting assigned anything, they're just being compared to parameterized values. Since this is a new row you haven't inserted yet, all the other columns are naturally NULL, so the comparisons will be NULL. Therefore `AND`-ing them together will be NULL, and that's the ultimate value that will be assigned to your `timeDate` column.

The other columns are not assigned any value in this statement, and their default is presumably NULL.

This is a weird and useless statement, but strictly speaking, it's not an error.

I also encourage you to use PDO more simply. Instead of using `bindParam()` for everything, you can pass an array to `execute()`. This does the same thing as if you had done `bindValue()` for each of the parameters. You can do this with named parameters or positional parameters.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
  "timeDate" => $date,
  "name" => $name,
  "mail" => $mail,
  "comment" => $comment,
  "website" => $website]);
```

This is especially handy if you already have your parameter values stored in an array.

The protection against SQL injection is just as good as using `bindParam()`.